# Sum of two surjective operators

Tags: operator-theory

It is well-known that the sum of two surjective operators isn't (in general) a surjective operator (for example consider $A+(-A)$). When it happens that the sum of two surjective  operators is still surjective? Namely, let $A,B:X\rightarrow X$ ($X$ Hilbert space) be two surjective operators, what are the properties that we can add to operators $A$, $B$ so that $A+B$ is surjective?

Comment: The question is too vague to admit a useful answer. It is like asking "What conditions can we put on two integers $A$ and $B$ to make their sum non-zero?" As you probably have a particular application in mind, which already has some extra structure, it might be better ask about the specific situation that you have.

Comment: No, actually it happened to consider a sum of operators and wondered when their sum could be even surjective. However, you're right, it is perhaps too vague question.

Comment: You've accepted an answer with a very strong additional assumption, namely finite dimension. You're not interested in other cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In finite dimensions, surjective = injective, and the condition is that $B^{-1}A$ does not have $-1$ as an eigenvalue.

Comment: Thank you! But, why $B^{-1}A$  does not have −1 as an eigenvalue?

Comment: $A+B$ is surjective if and only if $B^{-1}A + 1$ is surjective if and only if $B^{-1}A+1$ is injective.

Answer (score 1):

If you ask that $||B||\leq \frac{1}{||A^\dagger||}$ it works. It comes from:

If has a $G$ closed range, $A$ bounded, $||G-A||\leq \frac{1}{||G^\dagger||}$ then $A$ surjective.

Note: $A^\dagger$ is the pseudoinverse of $A$.